# Apply custom modifications to the model in 3D software and export the TGA

Tags: 3d, adobe-dimension

My problem might not be quite clear from the title so it needs some further explanation here.

I'm not limited to using Adobe Dimension that's just one piece of the software I'm trying out.

What I want to do (I have zero success with this):

- Load the .obj model into 3D Software;
- Apply .tga texture;
- Apply some custom modifications (anything) in the 3D software;
- Export the .tga which should be changed according to those custom modifications.

So it's like painting on .tga but in 3D. Then exporting and polishing it out. Hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: A quick search using terms "apply TGA to object Blender" resulted in a number of useless links, but about as many with some indication that what you ask is possible. Unfortunately, Blender is a rather complex, powerful and free program with a substantial learning curve. It likely will do what you require, if you are persistent.

Comment: @fred_dot_u thanks. the easy example is adding a texture to the .obj in Dimension, adding material to the initial object and exporting the texture with that material applied.